# C++11 - lambda function pass vector in capture and modify it

Tags: c++11, lambda

I have this code:

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <functional>
#include <vector>

int main () {
  std::vector<int> kk;
  kk.push_back(2);
  std::function<int(int)> foo = std::function<int(int)>([kk](int x)
  {
      kk.push_back(1);
      return kk[0]+1;
  });

  std::cout << "foo: " << foo(100) << '\n';

  return 0;
}
```

Why I cannot modify vector `kk`, passed via capture, inside lambda function?

I got this error:

> 11:21: error: passing 'const std::vector' as 'this' argument of
>   'void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::push_back(std::vector<_Tp,
>   _Alloc>::value_type&&) [with _Tp = int; _Alloc = std::allocator; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::value_type = int]' discards qualifiers
>   [-fpermissive]

I can pass it by reference, but problem is, that it will go out of scope if my lambda is called from thread and vector will no longer be available.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default, a closure type declares its `operator()` as `const`-qualified member function. Which means objects captured by copy cannot be modified inside the lambda. To make the `operator()` a non-`const` member function, you have to mark the lambda `mutable`:

```
std::function<int(int)> foo{[kk](int x) mutable
{
    kk.push_back(1);
    return kk[0]+1;
}};
```

[[Live example]](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/efc6dd4e235da48a)

(I also took the liberty of removing the double type specification in the declaration).

Of course, bear in mind that the copy of `kk` made in the capture is local to the lambda object. The local variable `kk` in `main` will not be modified by calling `foo`.

Comment: Is kk changed outside even that you did not pass as a reference?